# installing odoo for the first time

Tags: python, odoo

I tried to install odoo for the first time using this commande on ubuntu 14.04:

```
$> wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
$> echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
$> apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

But when I try to run odoo, I get this error message:

```
***error: [Errno 98] Address already in use***
```

Comment: There might be an odoo instance already running. Check `ps -ef | grep odoo`. Run `sudo /etc/init.d/odoo restart`, if there is.

Comment: Chances are that by installing odoo that way, it will start odoo by itself in an `init` job. If you want to kill it you probably have to call something like `stop openerp` or `stop odoo` with root rights.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the port that Odoo is trying to use (8069 by default) is already in use by another process. You can look for that process via

```
sudo netstat -tupln | grep 8069
```

You can then either kill whatever process is currently using that or simply select a different port for Odoo to run on (such as 8080).

```
odoo --xmlrpc-port=8080
```

More information is available on Odoo's [discussion](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-the-default-port-8069-used-by-odoo-server-60679) boards

Comment: There might be an instance automatically getting lunched in an init script

Answer (score 0):

First you fetch the process ID by firing the following command:

```
ps aux|grep openerp
```

Then you will see :

```
odoo 1314  or something else like odoo xxxx
```

Note down that ID and fire following command:

```
sudo kill -9 proceesID [ex: sudo kill -9 1314 where 1314 is process id]
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` unless you really need to. `SIGTERM` should be just enough.

Answer (score 0):

***Solution for Address already in use in Odoo 10 in Ubuntu 16.04:***

```
ps -ef | grep odoo
```

Look for the one which looks like this

```
dhaval   3365  2540  1 15:42  00:00:00 /usr/bin/git/odoo10/odoo-bin
```

Just kill the instance by

```
sudo kill -9 3365
```

3365 is mine, you can use the one which you are able to see.